# Android Real time Crash in tgkill

Tags: android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm seeing this native crash with the following stack trace.
Currently, I am getting crash in android version: Android 6.0 Android 5.1

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
native: pc 0000000000044310  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  native: pc 0000000000041f11  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
  native: pc 000000000001ba13  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  native: pc 0000000000018c81  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
  native: pc 0000000000016840  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  native: pc 000000000001a627  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16)
  native: pc 000000000001a63f  /system/lib/libc.so (__fortify_chk_fail+18)
  native: pc 00000000000480fd  /system/lib/libc.so (__FD_SET_chk+24)
  native: pc 000000000000a5f5  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
  native: pc 000000000000b1cb  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
  native: pc 00000000034eed1f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080809/android-7-native-crash-libc-so-tgkill