# Android 7.1 and 7 Native Crash: libc.so tgkill+12

Tags: android, crash, native, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I'm seeing this **native crash** with the following stack trace.

I have checked other questions similar to this but doesn't found anything similar solution as I have not used TextureView or CardView and I am also sure that it is not due to any library dependencies.

**Can anyone have clue, Please?**

```
#00 pc 000000000004ae30 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00000000000485c3 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
#02 pc 000000000001de5d /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 0000000000019561 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
#04 pc 00000000000171a0 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 000000000031e8fd /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+328)
#06 pc 00000000000b56d7 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1134)
#07 pc 00000000001be831 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+308)
#08 pc 000000000023c917 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+46)
#09 pc 00000000002822ef /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+418)
#10 pc 0000000000090abb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#11 pc 00000000029950cd /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.nCreate+96)
#12 pc 0000000002994e23 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.<init>+70)
#13 pc 0000000002994f91 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RenderNode.create+68)
#14 pc 00000000027526e3 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View.<init>+750)
#15 pc 0000000002752a57 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View.<init>+66)
#16 pc 0000000002a6d831 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+148)
#17 pc 0000000002a6d765 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+64)
#18 pc 0000000002a6d6f1 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+60)
#19 pc 0000000002a6d683 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.widget.TextView.<init>+46)
#20 pc 000000000003bd5b /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_17678_17678 (deleted)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 7 Native Crash: libc.so tgkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080809/android-7-native-crash-libc-so-tgkill)