# Android native crash - tgkill from google play

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting this backtrace, this only happens only on Android devices 7.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2.

Does anyone have an idea how debug it further or try to find a solution for it?

Google play logs, tgkill from google play

---

pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> name of the app <<<

```
  #00  pc 000000000006b5b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #00  pc 0000000000068a50  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000023f68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
  #00  pc 000000000001c9ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
  #00  pc 0000000000005c00  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+232)
  #00  pc 00000000000384e4  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaDataSource::JMediaDataSource(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+852)
  #00  pc 0000000000042654  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so
  #00  pc 000000000270575c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1fe1000) (android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource+152)
  #00  pc 0000000002706e74  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1fe1000) (android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource+48)
  #00  pc 00000000000d1eb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #00  pc 00000000000deb88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+208)
  #00  pc 000000000028dde4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+312)
  #00  pc 0000000000286dc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+592)
  #00  pc 00000000005568ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+452)
  #00  pc 00000000000c8614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
```

Sentry logs are sometimes different but the issue is the same tgkill, shows these missing on them

```
boot-framework.oat
libmedia_jni.so
liblog.so

libreactnativejni.so
libfbjni.so
base.odex
libc.so

libyoga.so
base.odex
libart.so
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 7 Native Crash: libc.so tgkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080809/android-7-native-crash-libc-so-tgkill)

Comment: I have looked into that one, it's not similiar to this error, thank you.

Comment: @Nur having the same issue. did you resolve it?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I didn't find anything directly related to this, but we did refactor the code: memoization and callback's and this error was not shown anymore.

We had a component incase the image was not provided from fetching, it was re-rendering unnecessary, we used memo on it.
I cannot remember any more details sorry.